# Setting delegate property without IB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, uinavigationcontroller

Does anyone show how to set the delegate properly for this without interface builder?

http://www.gauravv.com/2009/12/29/iphone-development-tip-custom-uinavigationbar/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, it inherits from `UINavigationBar` it will contain all of the same `@property`'s.  Thus you can do `self.delegate = delegateObject` and it will set the delegate of the nav bar.

If you are defining it in the owner class you would do the following:

```
navbar.delegate = delegateObject;
```

Comment: thx, i inverse it which worked for me, self.navigationController.delegate = navBar;